# Using Custom Push Segue in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In iPhone, when we use push Segue in Storyboard, it always navigates from `right` to `left`. Can we implement any mechanism that it navigates `left` to `right`, or `down` to `top`?

I know about how to create `Custom` Segue, but it does not work the same like `Push`. Can you help me?

Answer (score 12):

If you are developing an App for iOS 5, you can create a class that implement UIStoryboardSegue (to have custom segue), and then override the `Perform` method in this way:

```
-(void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; 
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; 

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: this is weird. in landscape (homebutton to left) it goes from top to bottom even when use kCATransitionFromLeft!!!! and if device is turned the other way (homebutton to right) it goes from bottom to top!!! any ideas why is this happening??